# mysql limit not work orderby with limit 0,5

Tags: php, mysql

```
$selectorders=sprintf("SELECT s.stud_rollno, s.admissiondate, s.fname, s.lname, s.gender, c.communityname, t.name, y.yearname, s.iname 
                       FROM erp.student s inner join year y 
                       on year_id = s.ayear 
                       inner join community  c 
                       on c.d_id = s.community  
                       inner join types  t 
                       on t.id = s.department 
                       ORDER BY s.stud_rollno 
                       limit 0,10");
$results = mysql_query($selectorders) or die(mysql_error());
$tot_rsselect = mysql_num_rows($results);
```

my runtime error is
**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 200' at line 1**

but run in localhost/phpmyadmin page.

Comment: i have mysql server version 5.0.51

Comment: I dont think its the limit which is causing the issue,its something else one thing change `inner join year y on year_id = s.ayear ` to `inner join year y on y.year_id = s.ayear ` and try to echo the query in PHP and see if there is some unwanted characters you have. Also the given query you have limit 0,10 but the error says 0,200 check if you are appending the limit again somewhere.

Comment: but its work in localhost/phpmyadmin page. problem in runtime only.

Comment: is it work without after removing sprintf(), only simple string?

Comment: yes, it's work without after removing sprintf(), only simple string

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to select only top 10 rows. So in this scenario there is no need to use 0, 10 or like somthing. You can just simply write `LIMIT 10`

So your query will be:-

```
"SELECT s.stud_rollno, s.admissiondate, s.fname, s.lname, s.gender, c.communityname, t.name, y.yearname, s.iname 
 FROM erp.student s inner join year y 
 on year_id = s.ayear 
 inner join community  c 
 on c.d_id = s.community  
 inner join types  t 
 on t.id = s.department 
 ORDER BY s.stud_rollno 
 limit 10";
```

I'm not sure but this might be your solution.

Comment: Same error is displaying but correctly run in localhost/phpmyadmin page, You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 200' at line 9

Comment: Can you echo out the actual sql that is executed (ie use `$results = mysql_query($selectorders) or die(mysql_error() . " - " . $selectorders);` . Then we can see what MySQL is actually trying to execute.